# compare cisco firmware version using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have firmware image in my system and I am able to get the current version of cisco ap

```
    #! /bin/bash          
    imageFileName="ap1g2-k9w7-tar.152-4.JA1.tar"  

    #Get image file version in format as given below after using one function  
    imageFileVersion="15.2(4)JA1"
    #retrieve the current version from the cisco ap   
    currentCiscoAPVersion="15.2(4)JA1"  

    #Now we need to compare these two values as given below 
    if [[ "$imageFileVersion" -eq "$currentCiscoAPVersion" ]]; then  
        echo "update not required"
    else
        echo "update required "
    fi
```

I have tried but not able to compare in shell script (bash)

Comment: Must-haves of bug reports: ① What was done (including the complete situation)? ② What was expected? ③ What was observed instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compare arbitrary strings (which are not denoting integer values) with `-eq`.  That's wrong.  `-eq` is only for comparing integer values.

Use `==` to compare strings:

```
if [[ "$imageFileVersion" == "$currentCiscoAPVersion" ]]
then  
    echo "update not required"
else
    echo "update required "
fi
```

Or (what I'd prefer):  Use single brackets and single `=`:

```
if [ "$imageFileVersion" = "$currentCiscoAPVersion" ]
then  
    echo "update not required"
else
    echo "update required "
fi
```